# Submit data to an array on another page using JQuery and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, forms

I have this form. At the moment, it submits to my `cart.php`.

```
<form action="cart.php?ID=<?=$row['id'];?>&salec=<?=$row['sale'];?>" 
       method="POST">

   <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?=$row['title'];?>">

   <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?=$row['price'];?>">

   <input type="hidden" name="hidden_list_price" value="<? 
   =$row['list_price'];>">

   <input type="hidden" name="collect" value="<?=$row['collection'];?>">

      <h4>Quantity</h4>

   <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" maxlength="1" 
    class="quantity">

   <input type="hidden" name="himg" value="<?=$row['image'];?>">

   <input type="submit" class="button" name="cartbtn" value="Add to Cart">
</form>
```

It submits to this array that I have in my `cart.php`:

```
$_SESSION['shoppingcart'] = array (

        'salec' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'salec'),
        'id' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ID'),
        'name' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hidden_name'),
        'list_price' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hidden_list_price'),
        'price' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hidden_price'),
        'quantity' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'quantity'),
        'collect' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'collect'),
        'img' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'himg')

);
```

This works fine. I need to submit this `form` data to the `cart.php` `array` without the redirect (action).

I tried this jQuery and Ajax, but it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").on('submit', function(){
        var name = $("#hidden_name").val();
        var price = $("#hidden_price").val();
        var list_price = $("#hidden_list_price").val();
        var quantity = $("#quantity").val();
        var img = $("#himg").val();
        var collect = $("#collect").val();

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "cart.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                alert(result);
            }
 });
```

When I do this:

```
function pre_r($array){
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($array);
    echo'</pre>';
}

pre_r($_SESSION) ;
```

It shows me that the data has not been added to the array. It doesn't redirect me - which is what I want - but it also doesn't add the info into the array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have to [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) . Right now your form is submitting, then the ajax is performed (probably not anymore, because you already 'redirect' to cart.php before the ajax)

Comment: _but_ `datastring` is not defined anywhere!?

Answer (score 1):

if the form works fine when submitted without ajax then you need to submit the form as it is in the Ajax block also:

```
$("#myform").on('submit', function(e){
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url:  form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            alert(result);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: make sure your form id="myform"

Comment: thanks for the answer but unfortunately, this does not work. I made sure the forms id ="myform". This succeeds in not redirecting me, but it also does not add the form data to the array.

Comment: @K.Doe Using `serialize()` will send exact same data as the original submit process. Inspect request in browser dev tools network to see if status is 200 and to see exactly what gets sent. Also does your alert fire?

Comment: @charlietfl hi, the code is 200(ok). It shows all of the correct form data, query parameters when the submit button is clicked. It just, for some reason, does not add the data to the array

Comment: @charlietfl oh yes, I get the alert as well

Comment: have you started the session before calling $_SESSION? "session_start();"

Answer (score 0):

Hi I will try to help you .I will tell you i m new in this industry so i m still learning :) but i will start with :
1.changing that input type submit with type button.
``
`$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#myform").click(function(){
    var name = $("#hidden_name").val();
    var price = $("#hidden_price").val();
    var list_price = $("#hidden_list_price").val();
    var quantity = $("#quantity").val();
    var img = $("#himg").val();
    var collect = $("#collect").val();`
```

$.ajax({

```
        type: "POST",
        url: "cart.php",
        data: {
      name:name,
      price: price,
      list_price: list_price,
      quantity: quantity,
      img: img,
      collect: collect


     },
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            alert(result);
        }
```

});

See if you have some error into console hope this may help you 
ps if you want to make a post request with jquery you can do that in a easy way 

`$.post( "cart.php", {name:name,
          price: price,
          list_price: list_price,
          quantity: quantity,
          img: img,
          collect: collect } );`